# Batch Script to run a computer test

Tags: batch-file, usb, usb-drive

I am not really a programmer. I am a newbie.

Can you guys please help me with a windows batch file that will run a computer test?

- Detect any hard drives then run a chkdisk on them
- Detect any usb port
- Detect any flash drive plug in the pc
- Check the display pixels

I have started with this to detect the USB but somehow getting some errors

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set PNPDeviceID=4002FDCCE0E4D094
set Q='wmic diskdrive where "interfacetype='USB' and PNPDeviceID like '%%%PNPDeviceID%%%'" assoc /assocclass:Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition'
echo %Q%
for /f "tokens=2,3,4,5 delims=,= " %%a in (%Q%) do (
  set hd=%%a %%b, %%c %%d
  call :_LIST_LETTER !hd!)
goto :_END

:_LIST_LETTER
(echo %1 |find  "Disk ") >nul|| goto :_EOF 
for /f "tokens=3 delims==" %%a in ('WMIC Path Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition  ^|find %1') do set TMP_letter=%%a
set Part_letter=%TMP_letter:~1,2% 
echo %Part_letter% %1
goto :_EOF


:_END
:_EOF
:: *** end
pause
```

Comment: A good first step would be to tell us what those errors are.

Comment: Detecting flash drives is no easy matter with batch script.  I have tried it many times and never truly succeeded.  I would say it is beyond the scope of help in a simple question like this.

Comment: "Check the display pixels" = get the current display resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a batch script that does almost everything you need.

Checkdisk will run against any local fixed drives. You can have it run in a new window (`chkdskAsync=true`) or have it run inside the program (`chkdskAsync=false`). Additionally, specify the chkdsk flags using the `chkdskLaunchArguments=` variable.

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: Use these lines to specify how CHKDSK and Notepad will run
:: ===============================================
SET chkdskLaunchArguments=/F /R
SET chkdskAsync=true
SET launchNotepad=true
:: ===============================================

COPY /Y NUL C:\Users\public\data.txt >nul 2>&1
ECHO Getting drive(s) information
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('wmic logicaldisk get caption^, description^, providername^, volumename') DO (
    ECHO.%%A>>C:\Users\public\data.txt
)
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 skip=1" %%A IN ('wmic logicaldisk get caption^, drivetype') DO (
    IF %%B EQU 3 (
        IF "!chkdskAsync!" EQU "true" (
            START CMD /C CHKDSK %%A %chkdskLaunchArguments%
        ) ELSE (
            CHKDSK %%A %chkdskLaunchArguments%
        )
    )
)
ECHO Getting resolution information
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('wmic path Win32_VideoController  get CurrentHorizontalResolution^,CurrentVerticalResolution') DO (
    ECHO.%%A>>C:\Users\public\data.txt
)
ECHO Information gathered ... saved to C:\Users\public\data.txt
ECHO Showing results.
IF "!launchNotepad!" EQU "true" (
    START /WAIT notepad.exe /A C:\Users\public\data.txt
)
ENDLOCAL
EXIT
```

When it is complete it saves everything to `C:\Users\Public\data.txt`. It will also launch the file in notepad (if `launchNotepad=true` is set to ... true).

The output looks like so:

```
Caption  Description         ProviderName                               VolumeName                     

A:       Network Connection  \\somefileserver.domain\                       New Volume        
C:       Local Fixed Disk                                                                              
E:       Removable Disk                                                 someuser Drive           
H:       Network Connection  \\somefileserver.domain\users$\someuser  Data Share and User Home Dirs  
P:       Network Connection  \\somefileserver.domain\Data              Data Share and User Home Dirs  
S:       Network Connection  \\somefileserver.domain\share                                                         

CurrentHorizontalResolution  CurrentVerticalResolution  

1920                         1080
```

**NOTE:** Make sure to run this as an administrator. *If you want chkdsk to run*

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to grab all USB devices other than storage. Hope this helps!

---

I didn't realize this question is 4 years old. Going to leave my answer for posterity and anyone digging for answers.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend trying

```
chkdsk volume=C:\ D:\ E:\ F:\
```

to check the disks each as a separate volume